# ReactJS Append div to existing div based on button onClick

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, drop-down-menu

I would like to append div into the current div, having multiple divs but each with their unique items in the dropdownlist.

Based on other answers and tutorials I have managed to come up with this, but the duplicated div has the same value as the original div, and the value changes follows as the original div changes.

Is there any way for me to make it not having the same value as the one in above? I would also like to make it sortable in the future

Thanks in advance!

Sandbox for full code
https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-mestorf-k997d

Code for render section

```
    render() {
      return (
      <div>
        <h2>Sales Order</h2>
        {this.state.items.map((item, index) => (
          <span key={index}>
        <div>
           {/*dropdownlist for available items*/}
           <select
            name="sel"
            value={this.state.selecteditems}
            onChange={this.handleSelect(index)}
          >
          {this.state.data.map(item => 
            <option key={item.productID} value={item.unitPrice}>
              {item.itemName}
            </option>
          )}
          </select>

          {/*unit price*/}
          <p>Unit Price: RM {this.state.selecteditems} </p>

          {/*button to add quantity*/}
          {this.state.selecteditems.length ? (
            <button onClick={this.addPro}> + </button>
          ) : null }

          {/*textbox for quantity*/}
          {this.state.selecteditems.length ? (
            <input type="text" ref="quan" placeholder="Quantity" 
              value={this.state.quantity}
              onChange={(e) => 
                this.setState({quantity: e.target.value})}
              >
              </input>
          ) : null }

          {/*button to decrease quantity}*/}
          {this.state.selecteditems.length ? (
            <button onClick={this.decPro}> - </button>
          ) : null }

          {/*subtotal*/}
          {this.state.selecteditems.length ? (
            <p>Sub Total: RM {this.state.subtot} </p>
          ) : null }

          {/*button to remove all ements*/}
          <button onClick={this.handleDelete(index)}>X</button>
        </div>
        <br/><br/>
        </span>
        ))}
          <button onClick={this.addElements} >Add</button>

      </div>
    )  
  }
```

Code for appending the div

```
    addElements = e => {
      e.preventDefault()
      let items = this.state.items.concat([''])
      this.setState({
          items,
      })
    }
```

Comment: Hello @meiisenglish, where are going to get items that are going to differentiate each dropdownlist from other?

Comment: Could you please clarify: "Is there any way for me to make it not having the same value as the one in above?" What would you like to change? Based on what? What should it change to?

Comment: @MerciDieuKIMPOLO I am sorry but I don't really understand your question

Comment: @lehm.ro for each dropdown list the items should be different, as in the first dropdown list if the selected value "a", the second dropdown list should be default as "blank" unless selected "a". Basically when I add the second dropdown list, it should be empty by default, not inheriting the first dropdown list value

Comment: currently you are mapping one dropdown list for each item in items. So if your items keeps repeating the same info your drop down lists will be the same. Making items include "empty info" would create what you are looking for, but I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with that. What is your end goal? That would help to give you an answer that actually brings you forward. You might have a wrong approach here.

Comment: @lehm.ro Sorry what I meant was if you look at the demo in the sandbox, when I add a new dropdown list, both of the selected value are the same. How can I make it be that the second dropdown list selected value not following the same one above

Comment: Currently the value is empty on all lists in the demo. Where would you like to have the values from? A textfield? A list of possible options? If you say you don't want the lists to be the same, you need an alternative. Currently they are the same because they don't have any information to show.

Comment: Looking at your api, it is fetching data from a localhost backend that the sandbox has no connection to. Possibly add a response you get on your machine from ttp://localhost:55959/api/products so we can work with that :)

Comment: I am sorry I forgot it can only be seen from my side only, https://imgur.com/a/tlJb0Mb this is the example for it. I meant it for both dropdown list to have the lists of value, but the selected item in the second dropdown list differs from the first one

Comment: the api is fetching from an api controller created in asp.net MVC

Comment: @lehm.ro please look at the answer I just posted, thank you for the help :)

Comment: Happy to hear you solved your issue! :)

Comment: Please don't forget to accept your own answer once it lets you, so this question is closed :)

Comment: @lehm.ro accepted as answer, thank you for your patience!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the poor choices of word in my question, what I basically want is just to add another dropdown list with the default value from the same list of data from the API.

So what I did was basically created a new component and appended it into the current component

```
import {NewComponent} from './components/NewComponent';

class App extends React.Component {
 constructor()
 {
  super();
  this.state = {
    children: []
  };
 }

   appendChild() {
     this.setState({
       children: [
         ...this.state.children, <NewComponent/>
       ]
     });
   }

    render() {
      return (
      <div>
       <button onClick={() => this.appendChild()}>Append Child</button>
        <div>
         {this.state.children.map(child => child)}
        </div>
      </div>
```

Thanks to everyone who tried to help me, hope this can help anyone who come across this in the future.